# Typescript: Best way to create, save and search Objects

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to typescript and want to create a storage object.

The Object should look like this:

```
workoutResults: array { 
    workoutResult {
        dateOfWorkout: string
        rounds: array {
            sets:array {
                repeats: number;
                weight: number;
                duration: number;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a history of all workouts in the past and also want to get the latest workout results when the user starts a new workout.

At i just play around with the interfaces, but for some reason this doesnt work:

```
interface WorkoutResult {
    workoutDate: string;
    workoutSet: WorkoutSet;
}

interface WorkoutSet {
}

export class WorkoutDoPage {

    private workoutResults: Array<WorkoutResult>;

    constructor(private nav: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, public exerciseData: ExerciseData) {

        var testDate: any = new Date();

        this.workoutResults.push(testDate);

        console.log(this.workoutResults);

    }

}
```

Throws Error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

Maybe you can help me out a little bit :)

What's the best way to archive a data structure like this in typescript?

Comment: I think you still need to instantiate a default value for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize your array after declaration or in constructor:

```
private workoutResults: Array<WorkoutResult> = [];
```

or

```
constructor(private nav: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, public exerciseData: ExerciseData) {

    var testDate: any = new Date();
    this.workoutResults = [];
    this.workoutResults.push(testDate);

    console.log(this.workoutResults);

}
```

For the sub arrays you can go with something like:

```
interface WorkoutSet {
  repeats: number;
  weight: number;
  duration: number;
}

interface WorkoutRounds {
  rounds: WorkoutSet[];
}

interface WorkoutResults {
  dateOfWorkout: string;
  rounds: WorkoutRounds[];
}
workoutResults: WorkoutResults[] = [];
```

And then push full objects that contain these data into the WorkoutResults array.

Comment: Oh, that was easy. Havnt seen that. Thanks.

Do you have also an idea how to create the "sub-array" for the sets and repeats in the workoutResults Array?